# Con expression in two rasters ArcGIS, raster calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, con

I would like to write a condition in ArcGIS 10.1 in Raster calculator.

I have 2 overlapping rasters (Ras1.img, Ras2.img) with different attributes in attribute table:

- Ras1.img: Class - results of supervised maximum likelihood classification
- Ras2.img: Att   - landuse, raster converted from shapefile polygon format

I want to change pixel values Class in Ras1.img based on the values in Att, Ras2.img. something like:

```vb
if ((Ras1.img, Class == 20 & Ras2.img, Att == 5), then change Class value 20 in Ras1.img  to Class 25))
```

I can't figure that out. It is super simple in R, but I have no idea how to make it in ArcGIS 10.1.

I was trying to figure that out by : http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000zn000000

and applying something like:

```vb
Con(("landuse1" == 1) & ("landuse2" == 5), "landuse1" + "landuse2", 99)
```

but I don't understand where I specify the attributes of my rasters I would like to change?

Comment: Rasters usually have only thing which 'Cell value', no attributes. Indeed Raster calculator uses the Cell Value for the 2 rasters while comparing.

Comment: when I tried just a simple expression i.e. Con(("Ras1" == 20), 0, 25)   , I didn't get back a correctly reclassified output.. So I think I am making something wrong..

Comment: Question please, the reclassified rastes you have were produced from ArcGIS supervised/unsupervised tool ?

Comment: yes, Raster1 yes. The second is the true type of landuse, by which I want to correct my classification results

Comment: What I know that the output of supervised classified is not exactly RASTER image, even you may check the output file type. May be you need to convert this image to Raster.

Comment: I save them as .img files, both of my rasters

Comment: Have you used **Data > Export Data** for the classified layer ?

Comment: no, just added the .img as the output from ModelBuilder. the Ras2 is truly converted polygon to Raster, snapped to Ras1

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer your question to need to mine the comments for critical information.  I would recommend you review the `Con` documentation, since it's unlikely you are using it correctly (especially the bit-wise AND). I've always made `Raster` objects to use in Python expressions.

Comment: Hi, I modified my answer. isn't the .img fole considered as a raster as well? ok, i'll try to change that to ArcGIS raster object

Answer (score 1):

Try the Reclassify tool: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm

Open this tool and you should be able to input your raster, then redefine pixel value(s).

Comment: @maycca if you liked this answer please "accept" it so the question does not show as unanswered